# R extract function buffered points weighted mean not returning the right value

Tags: raster, r, extract

I want to do weighted area mean of raster cells included in buffered points,`spatialpointsdataframe` but from what I have noticed the extract function only includes raster cells having their cell centers inside the 7 meter buffer. Raster cell size is 12.5 meter. It would be great if the function could calculate a weighted area mean of all raster cells not just cells having their centers inside the buffer zone. Anyone have an idea how to solve this?
Code looking like this:

```
means <- extract(Raster, SpatialPointsDataframe, method='simple', buffer=7,weights=TRUE, normalizeWeights=T, small=T, fun=mean, df=T)
```

As an example this spatial point gets the value of one pixel with weighted mean `21`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem thanks to https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/8520/jeffrey-evans

Using his example

```
results <- vector()  
  for(j in 1:nrow(x)) {
       lsub <- x[j, ]
       cr <- raster::crop(y, raster::extent(lsub), snap = "out") 
       r <- as(cr, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
         names(r@data) <- "raster.value"
       r <- intersect(lsub, r)
       na.idx <- which(is.na(r$raster.value))
         if(length(na.idx) > 0) { r <- r[-na.idx,] }
       if (nrow(r) < 1) {
         results <- append(results, NA)
       } else {
         results <- append(results, weighted.mean(r@data[,"raster.value"], gArea(r, byid=TRUE)))
       }
   }
results
```